# Как проверить время?

Tags: c++, строки

У меня есть строка со следующем содержимым: `13:02:01`. И еще несколько таких строк.

Я разбил их по часам и записал в массив. То есть у меня в массиве `array[20]={"1","3" ...}`

Теперь нужно проверить на ночное или дневное время.

Алгоритм такой:

Если ночь (т.е с 21:00 до 5:00), то сделать что-то.

Собственно вопрос, как реализовать это условие?

Answer (score 2):

Разбивайте не по символам, а по числам, разделенными двоеточиями. И работайте...

Простейший способ *в С++* — с использованием `istringstream`, например:

```
void dayNight(string ss)
{
    int h, m, s;
    char c;
    istringstream(ss) >> h >>c >> m >> c >> s;

    if (h >=21 || h <= 5) cout << "Ночь\n"; else cout << "День\n";
}
```

https://ideone.com/tbHrsj

А можно совсем по-простому:

```
bool dayNight(const char * s)
{
    int t[3] = {};
    for(int i = 0; *s && i < 3; ++s)
    {
        if (isdigit(*s)) t[i] = t[i]*10 + *s - '0';
        else if (*s != ':') return false;
        else ++i;
    }
    int ts = (t[0]*60+t[1])*60+t[2];
    if (ts >= 21*3600 || ts < 5*3600) cout << "Ночь\n"; else cout << "День\n";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: только в коде есть логическая ошибка:)

Comment: @KoVadim Возможно. Какая? (Защиту от дурака я сознательно опустил для простоты.)

Comment: @Harry, `h` строго меньше `5`... или минуты проверять надо...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну, с одной стороны... а с другой — может, утро с 6 утра начинается? :)

Comment: у автора сказано хитро - до 5:00. если бы там было "включительно", тогда очевидно, что мой ответ был бы точно-точно правильным.  Но там нет такого слова. Поэтому у него ночь заканчивается либо в 5:00:00 либо в 4:59:59. Но уж точно не в 5:59:59.

Comment: @KoVadim Ладно, дописал и такую проверку. Чтоб не мелочиться — еще один способ анализа :)

Comment: я конечно дико извеняюсь, но это пропустить строку вида "::"...

Comment: @KoVadim А, таки да... Но я уже писал, что защиты от дурака не ставил, в первом варианте вместо ':' прошло бы что угодно. Да и проверки на корректность времени (типа, "89 минут третьего") тут тоже нет...

Comment: главное софт для медицины, авто и космоса не писать.

Comment: @KoVadim Ну, видимо, самая простая (в написании) защита от дурака — проверка указателя на строку (`sscanf` ее же не делает?) + `sscanf` + проверка, что вся строка исчерпана + проверка на диапазон значений. И все равно где-то да вылезет "Британская энциклопудия"...

Comment: а что такое "проверка указателя на строку"? что по указателю лежит что то с нулем в конце?

Comment: @KoVadim Что там не нулевой указатель. Одно дело, если вы `string` передаете в свою функцию, но я-то — указатель...

Comment: учитывая политику разработчиков стандарта, можно просто написать коммент, мол не передавай nullptr и этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Есть много способов это сделать и проверить. Вот для начала старый надежный способ

```
std::string t = "5:00:00";
int h, m, s;
if (sscanf(t.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s) != 3) {
    std::cout << "oops\n";
} else {
    if (h >= 21 || h <= 4 || h == 5 && m == 0 && s == 0) {
        std::cout << "Ночь\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "День\n";
    }
}
```

да, я тут считаю, что 5:00 - это ещё ночь, а 5:00:01 - уже день:)

В 20 стандарт подвезли [chrono/parse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse), но там даже примеров нет. думаю, через пару лет можно будет использовать.

Можно парсить и регулярками, но мне способ с sscanf нравится больше

```
std::string t = "5:00:00";
std::regex re("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)");
std::smatch mt;
if (std::regex_match(t, mt, re)) {
    int h = std::stoi(mt[1].str());
    int m = std::stoi(mt[2].str());
    int s = std::stoi(mt[3].str());

    if (h >= 21 || h <= 4 || h == 5 && m == 0 && s == 0) {
        std::cout << "Ночь\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "День\n";
    }
} else {
    std::cout << "плохая строка, не парсится\n";
}
```

Если же хочется с++'ней способа, то вот он

```
#include <iomanip>      // std::get_time
#include <ctime>        // struct std::tm
#include <sstream>

struct std::tm when;
std::stringstream s("05:00:01");
s >> std::get_time(&when,"%H:%M:%S");

if (s.fail()) std::cout << "не могу парсить\n";
else {
    std::cout << when.tm_hour << ":" << when.tm_min << ":"  << when.tm_sec << "\n";
    if (when.tm_hour >= 21 || when.tm_hour <= 4 || when.tm_hour == 5 && when.tm_min == 0 && when.tm_sec == 0) {
        std::cout << "Ночь\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "День\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все, я понял. Можно еще проще, без регулярок и парсинга. Просто разбить строку на первые два элемента. Например, если строка со временем содержится в массиве array.

```
  string array[8]= {"13:02:01"};
            int c;
            c = ((int)array[0] - '0') * 10;//умножение на десять, чтобы получить десятки
            int b = (int)array[1] - '0';
            c += b;
```

Просто преобразуем первые два элемента в инт, а потом вычитаем код символа ноль из ASCII. То есть, по таблице ASCII код символа "1" это 49, а код символа "0" это 48, 49-48 = 1. Код символа "3" это 51, 41-38 = 3. Умножаем на 10, чтобы получить десятки. Дальше, складываем c и b и получаем число 13, а дальше просто реализуем условие:

```
if (c > 21 || c < 6){
    //выполнить что-то
}
```

Comment: да, так можно, и иногда это очень хороший, надежный вариант. но достаточно, что бы пришло время "1:00:00" и будут проблемы.